# Mongodb arroja resultado failed con exit-code

Tags: mongodb

Cuando inicio mongodb con `sudo systemcls start mongod` y luego pregunto por sus estatus con `sudo systemcls status mongod` me aparece el mensaje de la imagen. Estoy usando debian 11. Muchas gracias de ante manos por vuestra ayuda.

[image: Mensaje de failed de status en mondodb]

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré el problema. Lo único que hay que hacer.

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

Esto es debido a que el archivo `mongodb-27017.sock` pertenece a `root`; por lo tanto, el usuario `mongodb` no tiene permiso para ejecutarlo.